# Identification of an insect (?)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This one was found in the woods of northern Poland. It was about 5 cm long and crawling pretty dynamically. For me it seemed a little too big for a butterfly larva.

[image: Larvae?]

What is it called?

Comment: Related: [What kind of creature is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/56667/16866)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an  elephant hawk-moth, *Deilephila elpenor*. Here is an image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deilephila_elpenor) to compare with:

[image]

Comment: Agreed; that's definitely it. Since OP saw it in Poland I don't know if a (British) 20p will be helpful for scale; for non-UK readers, the coin is 21.4mm in diameter so size is spot-on.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is the larva of the sphinx purple butterfly.

[image: larva]

[image: buterfly]

Size of the larva is arround 70 mm

Comment: I haven't heard it called that before but from the photo it sounds like this is an alternative common name for *Deilephila elpenor*. Nice photos!