# What kind of creature is this?

Tags: zoology, species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

[image: Has two heads, and three eyes, there are videos also, behaves rather like a snake.]
I saw this on Facebook today and have tried researching it myself, but I have had no luck.

Answer (score 45):

This actually looks like a **Gaudy Sphinx caterpillar** ([*Eumorpha labruscae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eumorpha_labruscae)). It only mimics the appearance of a snake!

[image: Gaudy Sphynx Caterpillar]

[image: Gaudy Sphynx Caterpillar]

You can find more information about this species [here](http://www.butterfliesandmoths.org/species/Eumorpha-labruscae).

- **Range**: Argentina north through Central America, Mexico, and the West Indies to Florida, Mississippi, South Texas, and Arizona. Strays to Missouri, southern Michigan, Pennsylvania, Maine, and southern Saskatchewan.

You can find more pictures [here](http://hasbrouck.asu.edu/neotrop/entomology/taxa/index.php?taxon=76793&taxauthid=1&cl=12) or videos [here](http://www.ra-bugio.org.br/ver_especie.php?id=632) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVasvx6HM-A). Also the below gif (see whole video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEQTugk1iQw)) demonstrates the ability of this caterpillar to vibrate its tail end to -- as far as I can tell -- imitate a snake's rattle:

[image: caterpillar wagging "tail"]

Below is a picture of an adult moth from [UC Berkeley](http://calphotos.berkeley.edu/cgi/img_query?enlarge=0000+0000+1013+1665):

[image: Eumorpha labruscae adult]

Comment: Wow that is freaking awesomeness!! That first pic is truly amazing. +1

Comment: @AliceD Right?!  Google "snake mimic caterpillar" to see some other really cool species!

Comment: [Here](http://www.treehugger.com/natural-sciences/nature-blows-my-mind-caterpillar-looks-like-snake-hemeroplanes-triptolemus.html) is one of the cooler examples of snake mimicry! It even has a wiggling tail!!