# Caterpillar resembling a snake

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

I found a very interesting caterpillar. It's 5 cm long and  looks like a snake. I discoved it in a greenhouse on a vine in the Czech Republic.

[image]

---

I found two types: a green one and a brown one, both with same length.

### [image]

What species is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the larvae of an **elephant hawk moth** ([***Deilephila elpenor***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deilephila_elpenor)).

[image]

<sup>Green Variant. ©2005 [Henk Wallays](https://calphotos.berkeley.edu/cgi/img_query?stat=BROWSE_IMG&where-lifeform=Invertebrate-Insect&where-taxon=Deilephila+elpenor&title_tag=Deilephila+elpenor)  ([CC BY-NC 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/))</sup>

- In the [Sphingidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphingidae) family (like the snake-mimic caterpillar in [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/56673/16866)).

**Description**: typically brown-gray color with black dots along length of body. Young larvae are yellowish-white or green, but some mature larvae also can be green colored. Fully-grown caterpillars reach 7.62 cm in length.

- Have a backward curving spine or "horn" on the final abdominal segment.

[image: D. elpenor variation]

<sup>*D. elpenor* color variation. Source: [A.R. Pittaway & I.J. Kitching](http://tpittaway.tripod.com/china/d_elp.htm)</sup>

**Range**: Most common in central Europe and is distributed throughout the palearctic region.

**Habitat**: variety: including rough grassland, heathland, sand dunes, hedgerows, woodland, open countryside, and even urban gardens.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deilephila_elpenor)